# How to get Total of counts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm trying to get Total number of count per column. Here is example of what I need:

```
Grade Count Name 
9         1  Jon 
10        3  Ash
```

I would like to get Total under my Count column what will give the sum of 1 and 3.
Here is my query:

```
select grade, count(*) as count, name
from students
group by grade, name
order by grade, name;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Many databases support the `ROLLUP` clause.  If yours does, you can just do something like this:

```
select grade, count(*) as count, name
from students
group by grade, name with rollup
order by grade, name;
```

Technically, you would want the columns where the `grade` and `rollup` are both `NULL`, but this will give you partial totals as well.